# Calculating the fundamental units of integer ring using submodules

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have some extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$, where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ and some submodule $\mathbb{Z}[\theta'] \subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$. Is there a general method to calculate $[\mathcal{O}_K^\times:\mathbb{Z}[\theta']^\times]$, and, given this index, how would we go about determining $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ from $\mathbb{Z}[\theta']^\times$?

In particular, I am dealing with the example $\theta = e^{2\pi i/p}$ and $\theta' = \sqrt{\pm p}$, where the sign depends on $p$ mod $4$.

My thoughts were to consider a map from $\mathcal{O}_K / \mathbb{Z}[\theta']$ to some ring and note that units map to units; however, I am not sure if that fully corresponds with the units that I want.

Comment: Your orders live in different subfields, so you certainly cannot expect to compute the units in the cyclotomic field from units in the quadratic subfield.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I see. What if I instead consider the case $\theta' = \theta$? I'm aware that in the cyclotomic case above, they coincide, but what would happen in general?

Comment: If your order has finite index, then there is an ideal ${\mathfrak a}$ such that the elements $\alpha \equiv 1 \bmod {\mathfrak a}$ are elements of the order. If $\eta$ is a unit in the maximal order and $\eta^k \equiv 1 \bmod {\mathfrak a}$, then $\eta^k$ is a unit in the order. In the other direction you have to take $k$-th roots.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Fantastic, thank you! Do you have a reference for a proof of the result?